# Getting the status of Google Earth Engine task

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have queued earth engine task via a Google Service account. The following will generate a dataset and export to Google Cloud Storage

```
task = ee.batch.Export.table.toCloudStorage(...)
task.start()
```

I can use `task.status()` to check the status and the ID of task. Is there any way to get the status of a task for a given task ID?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/help

Answer (score 3):

The following works

```
ee.data.getTaskStatus("task id here")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also this very helpful command, which gives a list of all operations where you can get a progress fraction (progress of 1 means it's completed) and the operation ID (which is the same as the task ID).

```py
ee.data.listOperations()
```

Resulting in the output below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

`task.status()['id']`