# Google Earth Engine - How do I export image to cloud storage using Node.js?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, node-js, google-cloud

I am trying to use the Google Earth Engine API to generate images and upload to Google cloud storage via Node.js. I followed the [GEE guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/npm_install) to authenticate a Google Cloud project server side. I am successfully authenticating and initializing GEE, but cannot get images to upload to my Google cloud Storage bucket.

Here is what I have so far.

```
// Require client library and private key.
var ee = require('@google/earthengine');
var privateKey = require('./.private-key.json');

// Initialize client library and run analysis.
var runAnalysis = function() {
  ee.initialize(null, null, function() {
    var landsat = new ee.Image('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA/LC08_123032_20140515')
        .select(['B4', 'B3', 'B2']);

    landsat.getMap({min: 0, max: 1000}, function(map) {
        console.log(map);
    });  

    var url = landsat
        .visualize({bands:['B4','B3','B2'], gamma: 1.5})
        .getThumbURL({dimensions:'1024x1024', format: 'jpg'});

    console.log(url);

    // Create a geometry representing an export region.
    var geometry = new ee.Geometry.Rectangle([116.2621, 39.8412, 116.4849, 40.01236]);

    var task = ee.batch.Export.image.toCloudStorage({
        image: landsat,
        description: 'imageToCloudExample',
        bucket: 'my-bucket',
        fileNamePrefix: 'exampleExport',
        scale: 30,
        region: JSON.stringify( geometry.toGeoJSON())
    });
    
  task.start(function () {
    console.log('Started task #' + task.id);
    }, function (error) {
      console.log('Error: ' + error);
    });


  }, function(e) {
    console.error('Initialization error: ' + e);
  });
};

// Authenticate using a service account.
ee.data.authenticateViaPrivateKey(privateKey, runAnalysis, function(e) {
  console.error('Authentication error: ' + e);
});
```

When I run this, I see a task id printed to my console, but nothing is making it to my cloud storage.

```
Started task #3e174fb0-0107-47f6-b4d6-3ac5ef2247a0
```

Does anyone know the proper way to export from GEE to cloud storage using node.js?

Comment: Can you see the task if you go to the Code Editor? Missing, failed, completed?

Comment: I couldn't actually see the tasks in the Code Editor, which was surprising to me because I thought it would show all the tasks attached to my account. I could see them when I called ee.data.listOperations() when debugging. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being an authorization error being thrown on the Google Cloud Storage end. Unfortunately, the error wasn't bubbling up through the callback function. I ended up discovering it by calling `ee.data.listOperations()` while debugging and seeing that the tasks failed to complete and the error thrown. See [this question and answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/377335/getting-the-status-of-google-earth-engine-task) for more explanation on `ee.data.listOperations()`.